# sh step in dockerfile agent running using rootless podman hangs

Tags: jenkins, podman

I am trying to use `dockefile` agent with (rootless) Podman (yum install `podman-docker`), but the `sh` step that should run commands in the container hangs.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/python-36:1-164
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile true
    }
    stages {
        stage "stage", {
            steps {
                sh "echo hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins then tells (after hanging a longer time between the "sh" and "process apparently never started")

```
[Pipeline] { (Generate CryptoStore dist zip)
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@tmp/durable-5572a21e
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
```

setting `LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS`, it tells

```
sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@2@tmp/durable-baac9648/jenkins-log.txt: Permission denied
sh: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@2@tmp/durable-baac9648/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: Permission denied
touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@2@tmp/durable-baac9648/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
mv: cannot stat '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@2@tmp/durable-baac9648/jenkins-result.txt.tmp': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/--%<--@2@tmp/durable-baac9648/jenkins-log.txt': Permission denied
[...]
```

I see Jenkins starts the container with a `-u` option corresponding to the user the Agent that starts the container is running as, but podman mounts the volumes as root.

How to fix or workaround that? The plugin does not seem to have an option to override the user, adding a custom `-u` option to `args` does not seem to help, the `docker run` jenkins shows then simply contains two `-u` options but the first (the jenkins one) seems to be used...

Answer (score 1):

Looking into how to change the user for the volume mount I discovered this troubleshooting info: [Passed-in devices or files can't be accessed in rootless container **(UID/GID mapping problem)**](https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/troubleshooting.md#34-passed-in-devices-or-files-cant-be-accessed-in-rootless-container-uidgid-mapping-problem)

which describes some workaround but also contains this hint:

> A side-note: Using `--userns=keep-id` can sometimes be an alternative
> solution, but it forces the regular user's host UID to be mapped to
> the same UID inside the container so it provides less flexibility than
> using `--uidmap` and `--gidmap`.

As Jenkins steals us the flexibility here anyway, I added `args "--userns=keep-id"` to my `dockerfile` options and it works fine now. :)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename 'Containerfile'
            
            // Jenkins sets the user in the container to the same one running it
            // Using (rootless) podman as docker this breaks the -v volume mounts because the user in the container is mapped to a different one on the host.
            // this options disables that mapping, so the uid inside and outside match again.
            args "--userns=keep-id"
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage "Generate CryptoStore dist zip", {
            steps {
                sh "echo hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```